# how to receive two output value in a function node in node-red

Tags: javascript, node-red

In node red application I am used exec node for getting the mac address and same time using sq-lite database for get the values. I need to get the mac database node output and get mac from device node output in Get mac function.

I tried below code to get the output.

```
var databaseoutput=msg.payload;
var device_mac = msg.payload;
return msg;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Every Node-RED node only handles one message at once, so even if you wire 2 inputs to the start of the function node it will see 2 totally separate messages, one for each branch of the flow before it.

There are 2 options to deal with this.

1. Use the join node before the function node. Configure the join node to wait for 2 messages. This will then output a message with the payloads from the 2 input messages stored in an array which you can then query for the values you are looking for.
2. Look at using topics to distinguish between the 2 messages as they come in from the separate branches and then use the `context` ([docs](https://nodered.org/docs/writing-functions#storing-data)) to store the last value for each input, then when you have both inputs you can do the processing you need.

Comment: Perhaps if you explained what you're going to do with the 2 bits of information a more comprehensive answer could be given. What are the values you're getting from the database and how do they relate to the MAC?

Answer (score 0):

This same question was asked and answered in this [Node-RED google group discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/node-red/fuANasVtDzo/-M5lM4_VAAAJ)...

My suggestion is to NOT create multiple paths in your flow, that have to be combined before processing. It is generally easier and safer to chain those two functions together into one serial flow -- this avoids having to use context to hold values while waiting for the rest of the information to be generated.

Try calling the `exec` cmd first -- wire that to a `change` node, and "Move" **msg.payload** to somewhere else, like **msg.mac** -- wire that to the db query, which should put its output into msg.payload. The output msg should now contain msg.mac and msg.payload in a single msg object.